# Display the total number of emails in a folder instead of the number of unread emails?

Tags: macos, mac, apple-mail

On Apple Mail's left menu, I would like the total number of emails (both read and unread) in each folder to be displayed instead of the number of unread emails.

I haven't found any setting nor third party tool that lets you do that. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

In the title-bar of Mail.app it actually lists the unread and total messages in the mailbox (folder) you have currently selected.

In the ‘Get Account Info…’ pane (accessed by ctrl-clicking the mailbox items), there is an overview list of all mailboxes and message counts.

I think the answer you wanted was a badge next to each folder name giving item and unread count. I do not think this can be done in the currently shipping version of Apple Mail.

Comment: Thanks Dipak. The last section summarizes exactly what I am looking for. And everything you wrote is useful.

Answer (score 3):

If you select all the emails in a particular box (cmd A) you get a count up in the title bar. (Does not flip the un-read flag).

Answer (score 2):

I just downloaded a trial version of [Dockstar](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/dockstar/) and it seems to be doing what I need it to. I think it would address this question pretty.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same problem after software updates to Mac OS 10.9.5.

If someone already mentioned this approach, I apologize for repeating.

I have messages both "On My Mac" (Messages I save directly on my hard drive)  and on my MS Exchange account on the server.  Some of the confusion comes in because "On My Mac" emails are not show when you use "Get Info."  Only the messages that are on the server are shown.

To see how many messages are in a given subfolder under the folder "On My Mac":
A simple work-around is to make sure your folders are showing in your mail window (VIEW--->Show mailbox list).  Then select the folder you want from the list and select all the emails in that folder. Then look at the topmost information in the mail window.  It should have the name of the mailbox folder/ emails in that folder that you selected, and the total number of emails in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just open iCloud mail on the browser and hover over that tab to see the total count of all emails.
The sample is attached underneath:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Maybe that setting is in the same place that it's at in Outlook: right-click on a folder, select Folder Properties (or maybe just properties), and select a radio button that lets you select **unread** or **all**.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to downvote this. You can't just guess that Apple Mail works like Outlook. Clearly, it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately it is not the case.

Comment: I disagree that there is no value in "guessing." How many posts on forums know for certain that they are 100% correct? How many posts basically say "try this" or "try that"?